# How to error handle values stored as infinity (-1)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, infinity

I am trying to validate a form which returns the result (stored in a double) as -1.#IND (which I have been informed is infinity minus one?)
How can I trap this error?

**-- Background info:**
The form captures data about a real world object (with 100s of parameters), does a calculation which is handled by a service which returns a result via a 'result' object. The calculation service is doing several calculations which are stored as doubles in the object. There are 6 results returned by the service. The results should fall in the range 0-100.
I assume that a divide by zero has occurred somewhere in the calculation which results in the condition mentioned but would like to trap this condition to provide a more specific error message.

Note: I do not have access to the calculation service code.

At the moment I just want to test (pseudo code):

```
If myRating.value = -1.#IND Then
    ReportError("Divide by zero occurred somewhere in the calc")
End if
```

Comment: How is this "result" being returned to you? What sort of form is this? We're lacking all kinds of information here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how this is actually represented, you should be able to use [Double.IsNaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Double.IsNegativeInfinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnegativeinfinity.aspx) to test for not-a-number and negative infinity representations from Visual Basic.